# what is true about sequence $\cos(\tan^{-1}(\frac{-n}{2})^n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

consider the following sequence

> $$\cos\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{-n}{2}\right)^n\right)$$

which of following is true regarding above sequence.

1. sequence is convergent and monotonic
2. sequence is convergent but not monotonic.
3. sequence is not convergent.

my attempt:

i think its limit exists, and if it does then cos function cannot be monotone. but i am not sure about finding limit of given function.

Comment: Is it $[\tan^{-1}(-\frac{n}{2})]^{n}$ or $\tan^{-1}[(-\frac{n}{2})^{n}]$ ?

Comment: @raynor14  the second one

Comment: Then the sequence can be rewritten as $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(n/2)^n}}$. The denominator increases to infinity so the sequence decreases to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the identity

$$ \cos( \tan^{-1}(t) ) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}} $$

to make the problem easier to solve.

**Added:** You should be able to find the limit. It is $0$! Also you can prove that the sequence is monotone for $n\geq 1$.

Comment: i get $\frac{2^n}{\sqrt{4^n+n^{2n}}}$. what now?

Comment: @ketan: Now try to finish the problem.

Comment: i was stuck there. plz add some more explanation

Comment: @ketan: You should check if the sequence is monotone, convergent, or both!

Comment: plz give some hint on how should i evaluate that limit. i will try to finish the problem. just tell me whats the correct answer

Comment: @ketan: I added some materials but you should be able to prove what I added! By the way do you know how to accept answers?

Comment: @science are you sure it is monotone ?